# How to make node cms modular

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, modularity

I want to make my node cms (at this moment only login,reg, articles) modular. Like you can add or remove any module just be deleting or adding folder. But i cant find any correct or smart or any way to do it. Have you any experience, guides or examples that can help?

I am relatively new in node.
At this moment it looks like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit too broad in the context of creating a modular cms, however when talking about node modules, even if you just add or delete a folder you still have to `require` them in your code.

I would say that there are 2 types of plugins that you can have:

1. Supported plugins - plugins that you create and give the users the option to include them or not
2. Anonymous plugins - plugins that everyone can create, and need to be included in your application via some kind of interface.

The second type of plugins are more complicated, so I will refer only to the first type. An easy way to include them in your code is to have a JSON where you list the properties of each plugin, and then `require` each plugin in your code. Using `try/catch` will prevent your application from crashing if the plugin does not exist:

```
var allowedPlugins = [
  {name: "login", path: "login/index.js", loaded: false, module: null},
  {name: "reg", path: "reg/reg.js", loaded: false, module: null},
  {name: "articles", path: "articles/all.js", loaded: false, module: null}
];

allowedPlugins.forEach((plug) => {
  try {
    var module = require(plug.path);
    plug.loaded = true;
    plug.module = module;
  } catch(err) {}
});
```

Later in your code you can do:

```
if (allowedPlugins.login.loaded) {
  var login = allowedPlugins.login.module;
  login.doLogic(...)
}
```